# How to submit a form using Jquery dialog window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

In a **HTML table** I click on a cell to open a JQuery dialog window

```
<td>
   <a href="#" class="open" data-id="<?php echo $objResult["id"];?>">
    <?php echo $objResult["categoria"];?>
   </a>
</td>
```

After the table, I have this **FORM**, which is triggered in a JQuery dialog window.
As you can see, the form points to a page called `modcat.php`. The values of `categoria` and `hidden-id` are sent to the page.

```
<div id="finestra" title="modify" style="display: none;">
 <form action="modcat.php" method="POST" id="modcat">
      <select id="categoria">
       <option value="" disabled selected style='display:none;'> - seleziona -
       <option value="a">a</option>
       <option value="b">b</option>
       <option value="c">c</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="val" id="hidden-id">
 </form>
</div>
```

Finally, I have the following **SCRIPT** to submit the form.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.open").click(function () {
        var clickedLink = $(this); //get clicked link
        var id = clickedLink.data('id'); //extract id from data attribute
        $('#hidden-id').val(id); //update hidden field value with id
        $('#finestra').dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
    $('#finestra').dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: [{
          text: "modifica",
          click: function(){
          submitform();
          $(this).dialog("close");
          }
         },{
          text: "annulla",
          click: function () {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          }
         }]
    });
function submitform(){
    $( '#modcat' ).submit();
}
});
</script>
```

The form is shown correctly in the dialog window, but when I click on the button to submit it (the button called "modifica"), nothing happens. The page `modcat.php` does not receive any data from the form.
What am I missing here?

The modcat.php file is more or less as follows:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(TRUE);

$categoria = $_POST["categoria"];
$valore = $_POST["val"];

$update = mysql_query("UPDATE table
                       SET categoria = '$categoria'
                       WHERE id = '$valore'");

include 'close.php';
header('location:tabella.php');
?>
```

Comment: I think `form.submit` is a standard JS function, which would mean you need to apply it on the JS object, not jQuery one, by doing `$( '#modcat' )[0].submit()`

Comment: your code is working perfectly, check ``data-id`` value and add ``<select id="categoria" name="selname">`` select box name

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine. I think you are getting `$objResult["id"]` empty because this you are not able to set the `data-id' and you also did not set name of select attribute '<select id="categoria">`. So please check `data-id` value and set the name of select attribute.

Comment: How do you think I might check the 'data-id' value?

Comment: Have you print `$objResult["id"]` ?

Comment: I print it correctly in the dialog title using `$('#finestra').dialog('option', 'title', 'modify id number:' + id);`

Comment: Can you please do echo ` $objResult["id"]`  top on html table

Comment: Set some custom value in data-id like 12 etc and then check once because I have checked by custom value and it's working fine.

Comment: I've tried with custom values and nothing happens. Maybe the problem is that nothing is passed to the `modcat.php` file.

Comment: I have edited the question, to include the `modcat.php` file, where the form should post the data.